# Const variables must be initialized with a constant value - in a function

Tags: flutter, dart

I get this error:

```
Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.
Try changing the initializer to be a constant expression
```

My code:

```dart
  Future<void> _fetchData(String city) async {
    const apiURL =
        'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=(secret)=$city&aqi=no';
```

I get the error at the $city

Anyone can help?

Comment: `city` is a variable, and so not constant. Its value cannot be determined at compile time, declare it using `final`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Can't display a Column in combination with a BottomNavigationBar (Flutter 1.9.1)](//stackoverflow.com/questions/58255438/90527)", "[Const variables must be initialized with a constant value](//stackoverflow.com/q/64410237/90527)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you esentially doing string interpolation, hence your apiURL is dynamic, not const. use final instead

```
Future<void> _fetchData(String city) async {
    final apiURL =
        'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=(secret)=$city&aqi=no';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using $city (which receives the data from the argument), you can no longer define it as a const.

const variables are those whose values are pre-determined and do not change over time. e.g., http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json can be a const but http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=(secret)=$city&aqi=no cannot be a const.

Simply use final (recommended) or var and It should work just fine.